# How to pick CMYK color in round figure

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cmyk

Is there a way in Adobe Illustrator to pick CMYK color value from any part of a multi-color object in a round figure like this:
C- 95%
M- 10%
Y- 25%
K- 5%

not like this:
C- 95.23%
M- 10.15%
Y- 25%
K- 4.56%

Please let me know if there is a way in illustrator so that I don't have to round the CMYK values manually after picking the color.

---

**Edit for some of the commenters:**

[image]

@Scott, perhaps you are not clear about what I tried to say. I don't want to alter any color value. Please look at the attached image. Here you can see CMYK values for both Fill box and Color panel. Both CMYK values from same point of color picked from an image. But although CMYK values are showing in decimal values (51.76, 65.88, 81.18, 63.14) but the same point is showing CMYK values in rounding values (52,66,81,63). I like they would be same (ie, 52,66,81,63) for both Fill box and Color panel.

Comment: So you want the color picker to **inaccurate**?

Comment: I don't know why but if open the color picker (double click on the Fill box)  it will show the cmyk round values. The color panel show the decimal values instead.

Comment: @LeoNas Yes..that's the problem. Actually the color panel shows the actual value while the Fill box shows the round values. But in printing purpose, it is good to use the round values because the machine can't calculate decimal values accurately. Thus if you want the colors to be matched closely with your artwork color, you should use round values. But as the color panel does not pick CMYK in round values, I have to manually round the values. That's why I am asking whether there is any option to pick only round values in color panel.

Comment: @Scott , no I want the color picker to be accurate. Because even you see the CMYK values in the round from Fill box, but actually they aren't. They are in decimal places which you can see in the color panel. I want both CMYK values to be the same and round.

Comment: If you click each CMYK slider their values will be round.

Comment: If you want the picker to "round" then you are asking it to be inaccurate.

Comment: @Scott How? Are you telling that Color panel is inaccurate or Fill box is inaccurate?

Comment: If you don't understand that rounding will *alter the color*, then I don't know what to say.

Comment: @Scott, as the comment does not allow me to attach an image, I replied myself to my question. Please see my reply below.

Comment: just [edit] the question to add more information, don't use the answer field for that.

Answer (score 1):

The OS color picker is **not** highly integrated into Illustrator (unlike Photoshop). The color picker, when accessed from within Illustrator, is still driven by the OS to a degree. The rounding in the *picker* you see is driven by the **operating system**. Illustrator doesn't control that aspect of the picker.

You really should **always** use the **Color Panel**, never the color picker. The **panel** will be *more accurate* based upon your color settings within Illustrator. This is **especially true** if you are concerned with accurate color values.

In other words, the decimal numbers in the **panel** are *far more accurate* than the rounding taking place in the **OS** color picker.

Comment: This is completely new to me, and very valuable info Thanks, Scott!